# Set lua obj to nil from C++

Tags: lua

If I have a C exposed function to Lua where I pass in a userdata object as a parameter which is defined in lua, can the C function actually set that variable to 'nil' on the lua side?

```
// From C++

static void Delete(lua_State* L){
   // the first param will be userdata and I want to set it so after this call in lua happens whatever was passed in will be nil
}

-- from lua
local obj = CreateUserDataObject()

Delete(obj)

--I would want obj to now be nil
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do it that way.

In arguments to functions (both Lua and C) you get a copy of a simple immutable value, or a copy of reference to complex mutable value (table, thread, closure). Saving nil over that copy can't make initial value to disappear from Lua side.

You need a mutable context to make changes in Lua side from within C side. I.e. if erasable value is stored in a table (or any other indexable object) on Lua side, then C side needs to know that table and index of that value.

Comment: OK thanks. Wasn't sure if there was a way to get to the underlying object pointer to manipulate it and have that be reflected back in lua somehow.